# External link not showing on post but showing on comment

Tags: posts, comments, links, get-posts

Why is this? For example, if I input this in a post:

`<a href="http://i2.wearecdn.net/images/2012/11/47/article/vans/so6099412/vans-authentic-schuhe-bright-green-black-1755-zoom-0.jpg">This image here</a>`

It outputs a part of the link, instead of making "This image here" a link. So it will look like this:

`http://i2.wearecdn.net/images/2012/11/47/article/vans/so6099412/vans-authentic-schuhe-bright-green-black-1755-zoom-0.jpg">This here`

If I output the same in the **comment** beneath the same post, it shows it correctly. Is there a workaround for this problem? If yes, can someone help me out please? I would love that.

Comment: Where/how are you "inputting" into a post?

Comment: With a front-end post plugin. I guess it's called `User Submitted Posts`.

Comment: I guess the plugin is stripping HTML tags.

Comment: How can I check that?